# php script returns value despite neither "echo" nor "print" nor "printf" is used?

Tags: php

I've created this php script a while ago that is working well.

**UPDATE**

(Removed a lot of text that turns out not relevant for this problem.)

Only thing: I don't know why it is working. (returns $result and I don't know how)

**UPDATE**

Due to request here the original (sensible info replaced) script in question:

```
<?php

    $http_origin = $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'];

    if ($http_origin == "https://some.domains.tld" ||
        $http_origin == "https://some.domains.tld" ||
        $http_origin == "https://some.domains.tld" ||
        $http_origin == "https://some.domains.tld" ||
        $http_origin == "https://some.domains.tld")
    {
      header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ".$http_origin);
    }

    ### global variables
    $curl; $mode = $_POST['mode'];

    ### init logging
    $file = fopen('error.txt', 'w');

    ### log request source
    #fwrite($file, "request from: ".$http_origin."\n");

    ### create variable parameters
    $api_key='mysecretkey';

    ###Init curl
    #fwrite($file, "Ok, try to include curl..."."\n");

    try{
        $curl = curl_init();
    }catch(Exception $e){
        fwrite($file, "curl init failed. Look: "."\n".$e."\n");
        return null;
    }

    switch ($mode) {
        case 'alldatas':
            alldatas();
            break;

        case 'adata':
            adata();
            break;

        case 'register':
            register();
            break;

        default:
            return;
    }

    ###Get list of all datas
    function alldatas()
    {
        global $curl;
        global $api_key;
        global $file;
        $result;

        $params = ['api_key' => $api_key];

        try{
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://some.third-party.service/api/v2/ever/webinars");
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);

            $result = curl_exec($curl);

        }catch(Exception $e){
            fwrite($file, "data list failed. Look: "."\n".$e."\n");
            return null;
        }

        return $result;
    }

    ###Get a data
    function adata()
    {
        global $curl;
        global $api_key;
        global $file;
        $result;

        $data_id = $_POST['data_id'];

        if($data_id){

            $params = [
                'api_key' => $api_key,
                'data_id' => $data_id
            ];

            try{
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://some.third-party.service/api/v2/ever/webinar");
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);

                $result = curl_exec($curl);

            }catch(Exception $e){
                fwrite($file, "webinar fetch failed, man. Look: "."\n".$e."\n");
                return null;
            }

            return $result;

        }

    }

    ###Register user to a datas
    function register(){

        global $curl;
        global $api_key;
        global $file;
        $result;

        $data_id = $_POST['data_id'];
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $schedule = $_POST['schedule'];
        $timezone = $_POST['timezone'];

        if($data_id && $name && $email && $schedule && $timezone){

            $params = [
                'api_key'=>$api_key,
                'data_id'=>$data_id,
                'name'=>$name,
                'email'=>$email,
                'schedule'=>$schedule,
                'timezone'=>$timezone
            ];

            try{
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://some.third-party.service/api/v2/ever/register");
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);

                $result = curl_exec($curl);

            }catch(Exception $e){
                fwrite($file, "data list failed. Look: "."\n".$e."\n");
                return null;
            }

        }
        return $result;
    }

?>
```

Comment: SImplified version obviously lost some sensible code.

Comment: @u_mulder But what kind of code? Even in the full version there is no "echo", "print" or "printf" present in the entire file. So the question basically is: What other way of returning data exists / is left?

Comment: _What other way of returning data exists / is left?_ Anything not in PHP tags...

Comment: Something definitely must be output. Check developers console for raw messages from both scripts, what do you see there?

Comment: @AbraCadaver There is only php in that file.

Comment: @u_mulder I have added the original script to the post as you've suggested (I'm coming to think it doesn't return $result but $curl maybe??)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not setting `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` in your [`curl_setopt()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).  What that means is that when [`curl_exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php) is called, the result of the cURL transfer is *echoed* out!  That's where your returned data is coming from.

When `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` is `TRUE`, then `curl_exec()` returns the data and echos nothing.  But, when `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` is `FALSE` (or unset), then `curl_exec()` echos the data and returns `TRUE`.

Comment: Aha! Now I get it. My script worked by coincidence, then. Thanks very much for clarification!

Answer (score 1):

*curl_exec* echoes if you don't use

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

The old script uses [`curl_exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php) to output data.

By default [`curl_exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php) sends to output the content of the response it receives and returns the success of the operation. If you want it to not send the data to the output but return it, you must call [`curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) before `curl_exec()`.